# PHP - Formatting HH:MM:SS to 12hr HH:MM:a string

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm hoping this will be a piece of pie for someone! String output is currently 12:00am for everything.

The following code from MySQL with format HH:MM:SS (hours_open, hours_closed)

```
$get_hours_sql = "SELECT * FROM client_hours ORDER BY day"; 
$get_hours_res =  mysqli_query($dbConnect, $get_hours_sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));

// Establish the output variable
$hoursList = '<div class="right_bar">';
while ($productList = mysqli_fetch_array($get_hours_res)) {
    $id_hours  = $productList['id_hours'];
    $day = $productList['product_name'];
    $open = $productList['hours_open'];
    $close = $productList['hours_close'];

    $hoursList .= ''.date("g:ia", $open).' - '.date("g:ia", $close).'<br/>';
}

$hoursList .= '</div>';

echo $hoursList;
```

Output is currently

> 12:00am - 12:00am

looped.

I want to get the output to

> 11:00am - 11:00pm

which would represent the database entries.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the timestamps are stored correctly? Your code should show the time stored in the database.

Comment: Please, don't tell us whats in `$productList['hours_open'];` and `$productList['hours_close'];`, that would be to easy. We like to blindly guess.

Comment: I'm sure it would be a piece of pie for you as well if you perused the fine PHP manual :)

Comment: By the way, you're missing '; at the end of line 5.

Comment: @rdlowrey I've had a good look - can't see what's not working.

Comment: @Wrikken both vary from the database but are in 'TIME' format with HH:MM:SS i.e. '13:00:00'

Comment: Thanks @Tiddo. That was an error I missed when taking out some private code. It been corrected.

Comment: `date()` requires a [unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as the second variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find PHP <-> MySql date handling fiddly (got better with 5.3 though).

My guess is that the mysql query returns the date as a string and date() is expecting a time stamp.

Often, I just get mysql to format the date as a string for me and return it as an additional field, like so:

```
$get_hours_sql = "SELECT *,date_format(hours_open,'%h:%i %p') as hours_open_formatted, date_format(hours_close,'%h:%i %p') as hours_close_formatted  FROM client_hours ORDER BY day";
```

then just use the formatted fields:

```
$hoursList .= ''.$productList['hours_open_formatted'].' - '.$productList['hours_close_formatted'].'<br/>';
```

Comment: As I mentioned above just now - I can change the Datatype stored in the table. Which type should I be using for my existing method to work?

Comment: @user1108993 You don't need to change the type in the database. My method uses mysql's date formatting function to returns the dates in the exact format you want to display them.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @user1108993. No worries. FYI, the alternative would be to parse your mysql date field in php into a timestamp before passing it to the date() function. strtotime can do that but I've found it really unreliable outside of US date formats. PHP 5.3+ has a much better function called date_create_from_format (http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) which allows you to specify the expected format (ie. the mysql format) to make it reliable. Code Igniter also has a custom mysql date parsing function based on exploding the parts and using mktime..

Answer (score 1):

Data accepts as it's second parameter a Unix timestamp, so what you're trying to do simply won't work. You could use either mysql's TIME_TO_SEC function, or php's mktime to convert the time string to a Unix timestamp.

Example:

```
$openHours = explode(':',$productList['hours_open']); 
$timestamp = mktime($openHours[0],$openHours[1]);
$yourDate = date("g:ia",$timestamp);
```

Edit: I think you should try Ben's answer, I think it's a better solution than mine.

Comment: The database inputs are my own so I can change the datatype easily. What should I be changing it to for this method to work? TIME -> ?

Comment: How do you currently store the time?

Comment: explode(':',$productList['product_name']) ? you meant ['hours_open'], right?

Comment: HH:MM:SS with a 'TIME' datatype

Comment: @Ben You're right! So from you're php you're storing a string in the format HH:MM:SS to the mysql database? In that case you could either convert it to a unix time stamp when you store it, or when you retrieve it from the database, as in my example. When you store the time as a unix time stamp you should use an INT datatype

Comment: Thanks @Tiddo. I've gone with Ben's solution. Will see if that works permanently